# Add text to a cell without overwriting existing data

Tags: python, sql, django

I am currently working with one Django project.

I have the dictionary in it:

from models.py

```
class teltab(models.Model):
    code=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    telescope=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    comment=models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
```

and a form to add data to the dictionary:

```
class newtelescopesform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=teltab
```

Usually I get a comment from the form and writes it to the dictionary:

from views.py

```
if len(request.GET['comment'])>0:
                commentq=request.GET['comment']
                tel_list.update(comment=commentq)
                for item in tel_list: 
                    item.save()
```

But now I need to append a new comment to an already existing cell in the resulting table.

Namely my table looks like this

[image: Current table]

and I want to get this

[image: Table of my dreams]

Comment: What is tel_list? can you add it to your question? What database are you using?

Comment: It's a bad idea but, just use whatever syntax your database has for concatenating strings.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I have removed too much code, tel_list is basically: tel_list = teltab.objects.all(). Database is written on Postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

- In fact either you define new comment model with a **ForeignKey**: `teltab`

```py
   class telTabModel(models.Model):
       code=models.CharField(max_length=255)
       telescope=models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class CommentModel(models.Model):
        teltab = models.ForeignKey('telTabModel', related_name='comments')
        # ...
```

- Or if you are using PostgreSQL you can use [ArrayField as explained](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield):

```py
    from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

    class telTabModel(models.Model):
        code=models.CharField(max_length=255)
        telescope=models.CharField(max_length=255)
        comments = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200), blank=True),
```

- If you are not using PosgreSQL and you still want to use array you I will recommend [Jsonfield](https://github.com/bradjasper/django-jsonfield)

  ```
  pip install jsonfield
  ```

```py
    from jsonfield import JSONField

    class telTabModel(models.Model):
        code=models.CharField(max_length=255)
        telescope=models.CharField(max_length=255)
        comments = JSONField(default=[])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I still have problems with the code, but it helped.

Comment: what kind of problem you still have?

Answer (score -1):

I suppose u should change your model comment field type to TextField:

```
comment=models.TextField(blank=True)
```

Then just add "/n{new line}" to it
Edit: Dan's right, it s not a good idea there's opportunity to store lists in model if i'm not mistaken.